# Sails Js model atrributes set in array subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am trying to add attribute date in sails model sub document.But giving error.

```
{type:'array',model:'Recommendations'}
```

Recommendations.js

```
var Recommendations = {
attributes: {
    role : {type:'string'},
    user : {type:'string'},
    userName : {type:'string'},
    user_image : {type:'string'},
    user_status : {type:'string'},
    title : {type:'string'},
    description : {type:'string'},
    createdAt : {type:'date'},
 }
};
module.exports = Recommendations;
```

Anyone can help me...

Comment: What is your question???

Comment: How to set model attributes in array sub document ?

Comment: You can set type or model, but not both at once. If you want Array to contain elements from other model the only way is to write [custom validation rule](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations)